# How to implement serialization and de-serialization of a double?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, serialization, floating-point

I am trying to solve the relatively simple problem of being able to **write a double to a file** and then to **read the file into a double again**. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4733263/1097451) I decided to use the human readable format.

I have successfully circumvented the problems some compilers have with **nan** and **[-]infinity** according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7477978/1097451). With finite numbers I use the `std::stod` function to convert the string representation of a number into the number itself. But from time to time the parsing fails with numbers close to zero, such as in the following example:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>

const std::size_t maxPrecision = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits;
const double small = std::exp(-730.0);

int main()
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream.precision(maxPrecision);
    stream << small;
    std::cout << "serialized:    " << stream.str() << std::endl;
    double out = std::stod(stream.str());
    std::cout << "de-serialized: " << out << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine the result is:

```
serialized:     9.2263152681638151025201733115952403273156653201666065e-318
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  stod
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

That is, the number is too close to zero to be properly parsed. At first I thougth that the problem is that this number is [denormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), but this doesn't seem to be the case, since the mantissa starts with a 9 and not a 0.

Qt on the other hand has no problems with this number:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>

const std::size_t maxPrecision = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits;
const double small = std::exp(-730.0);

int main()
{
    QString string = QString::number(small, 'g', maxPrecision);
    QTextStream stream(stdout);
    stream.setRealNumberPrecision(maxPrecision);
    stream << "serialized:    " << string << '\n';
    bool ok;
    double out = string.toDouble(&ok);
    stream <<  "de-serialized: " << out << '\n' << (ok?"ok":"not ok") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
serialized:    9.2263152681638151025201733115952403273156653201666065e-318
de-serialized: 9.2263152681638151025201733115952403273156653201666065e-318
ok
```

Summary:

1. Is this a bug in the gcc implementation of standard library?
2. Can I circumvent this elegantly?
3. Should I just use Qt?

Comment: The hex format is there for roundtrip conversion. Last time I checked (last year?) both g++ and msvc were a bit deficient in support of that. But it's not difficult to cajole them into cooperating.

Comment: Answering question #2: This is probably my "C-way" kind of thinking, but you could copy the `double` into a `uint64` (mem-copying, not type-casting), serialize the `uint64` instead, then do the opposite on de-serialization.

Comment: @barakmanos Thank you! But wouldn't that be the same as using a binary format? I prefer to use the human readable one.

Comment: You'll serialize it into a different (yet readable) value. BTW, implementation-wise, perhaps you should serialize it into an array of `unsigned char` values instead, in order to avoid breaking strict-aliasing rules.

Comment: @barakmanos What do you mean by aliasing rules? Could you give me some references? I came across this approach in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4733588/1097451, but their approach does not handle infinities and nan.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thank you! So, does this classify as a bug?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: *Probably*. There's a big nest of bugs somewhere nearby this functionality. I've posted a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161720/fix-for-bizarre-a-format-behavior-with-g-4-9-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answering question #2:**

This is probably my "C-way" kind of thinking, but you could copy the `double` into a `uint64_t` (mem-copying, not type-casting), serialize the `uint64_t` instead, and do the opposite on de-serialization.

Here is an example (without even having to copy from `double` into `uint64_t` and vice-versa):

```
uint64_t* pi = (uint64_t*)&small;
stringstream stream;
stream.precision(maxPrecision);
stream << *pi;
cout << "serialized:    " << stream.str() << endl;
uint64_t out = stoull(stream.str());
double* pf = (double*)&out;
cout << "de-serialized: " << *pf << endl;
```

Please note that in order to avoid breaking [strict-aliasing rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), you actually do need to copy it first, because the standard does not impose the allocation of `double` and `uint64_t` to the same address-alignment:

```
uint64_t ismall;
memcpy((void*)&ismall,(void*)&small,sizeof(small));
stringstream stream;
stream.precision(maxPrecision);
stream << ismall;
cout << "serialized:    " << stream.str() << endl;
ismall = stoull(stream.str());
double fsmall;
memcpy((void*)&fsmall,(void*)&ismall,sizeof(small));
cout << "de-serialized: " << fsmall << endl;
```

Comment: Great! This seems to handle also infinities and nan.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: Yep, I was just about to add this notion in response to your comment at the question. Since all possible `uint64_t` values are "normal", there should be no issue with either `inf` or `NaN`.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: And again, at least on the theoretical aspect, you should mem-copy it to `uint8_t arr[sizeof(small)]`, because there is no guarantee by the standard that the compiler must allocate `uint64_t` and `double` with the same (64-bit) address-alignment.

Comment: For completeness, is this answer portable across systems of different architectures (e.g. ARM to x86)?

Comment: While this answer works, it's extremely wasteful and shouldn't be used in systems where space and performance matter. The other answer with `frexp` is the good one.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to other recording methods you can use `frexp`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>


const std::size_t maxPrecision = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits;
const double small = std::exp(-730.0);

int main()
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream.precision(maxPrecision);

    int exp;
    double x = frexp(small, &exp);

    //std::cout << x << " * 2 ^ " << exp << std::endl;
    stream << x << " * 2 ^ " << exp;

    int outexp;
    double outx;

    stream.seekg(0);

    stream >> outx;
    stream.ignore(7); // >> " * 2 ^ "
    stream >> outexp;

    //std::cout << outx << " * 2 ^ " << outexp << std::endl;

    std::cout << small << std::endl << outx * pow(2, outexp) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```