# Fix for bizarre "%a" format behavior with g++ 4.9.1?

Tags: c++, g++, printf, hex, compiler-bug

Compiler: 64-bit MinGW G++ 4.9.1 from the Nuwen distro, under Windows 8.1.

Code:

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_IOSTREAM
#   include <iostream>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>      // ::snprintf
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <stdexcept>    // std::exception

#ifdef snprintf
#   error snprintf defined as macro
#endif

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    auto const snprintf = _snprintf;
#endif

void test( double const value, int const precision)
{
    char buffer[34];
    snprintf( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), "%.*a", precision, value );
    printf( "Hex of %.3f with %2d digits: %s\n", value, precision, buffer );
}

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    try
    {
        for( int precision = 6; precision <= 8; ++precision )
        {
            test( 5.0, precision );
        }
        test( 0.0, 14 );
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "!%s\n", x.what() );
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

---

Works fine with Visual C++ (but Visual C++ appears to lack the opposite conversion):

```
H:\dev\test\so\0187>cl /nologo- /? 2>&1 | find /i "ler ver"
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.30723 for x86

H:\dev\test\so\0187>cl barx.cpp -D INCLUDE_IOSTREAM /Feb
barx.cpp

H:\dev\test\so\0187>b
Hex 5.000 with  6 digits: 0x1.400000p+2
Hex 5.000 with  7 digits: 0x1.4000000p+2
Hex 5.000 with  8 digits: 0x1.40000000p+2
Hex 0.000 with 14 digits: 0x0.00000000000000p+0

H:\dev\test\so\0187>_
```

---

Also works fine with g++ when `<iostream>` is *not* included:

```
H:\dev\test\so\0187>g++ --version | find "++"
g++ (GCC) 4.9.1

H:\dev\test\so\0187>g++ -std=c++11 barx.cpp

H:\dev\test\so\0187>a
Hex of 5.000 with  6 digits: 0x1.400000p+2
Hex of 5.000 with  7 digits: 0x1.4000000p+2
Hex of 5.000 with  8 digits: 0x1.40000000p+2
Hex of 0.000 with 14 digits: 0x0.00000000000000p+0

H:\dev\test\so\0187>_
```

---

**Bizarre result w/hang** when `<iostream>` is included:

```
H:\dev\test\so\0187>g++ -std=c++11 -D INCLUDE_IOSTREAM barx.cpp

H:\dev\test\so\0187>a
Hex of 5.000 with  6 digits: 0xa.000000p-1
Hex of 5.000 with  7 digits: 0xa.0000000p-1
Hex of 5.000 with  8 digits: 0x0.00000000p-33           ← Weird.
^C                                                      ← Hang, Ctrl+C
H:\dev\test\so\0187>_
```

I’m asking for a fix or workaround.

Comment: Do not get the problem in g++ 4.8.3/Cygwin

Comment: My workaround would be to stop using the legacy C stuff like `printf` within C++ :-) It was included (1) because C++ was originally a front end to C and (2) so C++ could make use of all the then-existing C code. If you're developing C++, _use_ C++: http://powerfield-software.com/?p=829

Comment: @paxdiablo not sure how that helps, e.g. iostream formatting may be implemented internally by calls to printf anyway.  I disagree with the advice in (4),  just because iostream exist does not make them superior (unlike the advice in the other points), there are valid reasons to use `stdio`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: g++ 4.9.1 does not support `std::hexfloat`.

Comment: g++ 4.9.0 also appears to be fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba3a2906585b17e4

Comment: This seems to be a MinGW problem, I can reproduce it with x64 versions of both MinGW-g++ 4.9.0 and 4.9.1

Comment: Please indicate _in the question_ whether this is MinGW, Cygwin or what. And your platform. Just saying "GCC 4.9.1" is insufficient detail.

Comment: Why do you reject `snprintf` being a macro, in this code?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Just to make sure that any problems don't stem from that in combination with the workaround for missing `snprintf` in Visual C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: added platform info, it's 64-bit MinGW g++ 4.9.1, Nuwen distro.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Your "platform" means what operating system you're using. So we're not quite there yet. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Windows 8.1, compiling from cmd.exe (not Cygwin). There's a lot of Visual C++ versions installed. However, since others have reproduced the issue I don't think it's related to use of some specific MSVC runtime. Also, it's Nuwen distro which defaults to static linking (rather big executables with no DLLs in sight).

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft's implementation has a number of `printf` bugs, and these affect MinGW by default ([#377](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/377/), [#407](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/407/), et al).

In all cases the recommendation [appears to be](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gnu%20printf/) to define `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` as `1` in the preprocessor to use MinGW's own ANSI-compliant implementation instead.

Presumably, Visual Studio has its own internal workarounds for the flaws in the underlying system code.

Comment: I wonder if this means they'll bother to fix `std::to_string` also

Comment: It still crashes with `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1`, but that's really useful to know about anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "hangs".