# Is it safe to assume that float or double NaNs will always be "nan" as a string?

Tags: c++, floating-point, nan

If I print a NaN via std::cout or convert it to a string, does the standard say it has to be "nan" as a string?

Are there other methods to convert a NaN to a string, where this is not true?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {    

    float x = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
    std::cout << x << '\n';                 // Output: nan
    std::cout << std::to_string(x) << '\n'; // Output: nan
    printf("%f", x);                        // Output: nan

    // possibly other variants to print x
}
```

Comment: No. In Windows/VC++ it looks different. (Unfortunately, I forgot how.) However, I found this Q/A: [SO: NaN ASCII I/O with Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7477978/7478597). (It shows what I roughly remembered.)

Comment: Found the same link as @formerlyknownas_463035818. It might be a bug how things are done in VC++. Unfortunately, the resp. link of Hans Passant is rotten.

Comment: I also ask about other variants than std::to_string, so not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: i think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7478290/4117728) covers using `cout` (even if the question is specifically about visual c++, I think the answer has a wider scope)

Comment: It drives me _crazy_ that Microsoft decided to summarily break all links to bug reports on their Connect platform, with absolutely no redirects or indeed any indication whatsoever how to find the moved content. It really says a lot about the culture there, in my opinion.

Comment: (Off-topic) Don't use `std::endl`, unless you really want a short form of `'\n' << std::flush`.

Comment: @NikosC. Edited. Doesn't really matter here though.

Comment: Infinity and negative infinity probably have similar portability concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is defined in terms of [std::sprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), which C++ adopts from the C99 standard library. And there it says:

> Not-a-number is converted to `nan` or `nan(char_sequence)`. Which one is used is implementation defined.

So the string will begin with `nan`, but there could be other characters after it.

Unfortunately, Microsoft's library doesn't seem to be compliant. See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7478290/856199

> So, after taking all that in, the end result is that your C standard library is not C99-compliant, since 1.#QNAN is not a valid output of fprintf according to the above. But, it's well-known that Microsoft's C runtime is not C99-compliant, and it doesn't plan to become compliant any time soon, as far as I'm aware.

---

*(Off-topic)*
Don't use `std::endl`, unless you really want a short form of `'\n' << std::flush`.

Comment: So Visual C++ is not standard comforming according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477978/nan-ascii-i-o-with-visual-c where it prints a nan as "1.#QNAN" ?

Comment: @nada That's correct, and Adam's answer on the question you linked to does say this (with an exploration of why)

Comment: Answer would be complete if it discussed `std::cout << x << std::endl`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Fair enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Nikos C. :

std::cout which is a [std::basic_ostream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) leads to [std::num_put](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) about formatting which says

> If the type of v is a floating-point type, the the first applicable
>   choice of the following is selected:
>
> ```
> If floatfield == std::ios_base::fixed, will use conversion specifier %f 
> If floatfield == std::ios_base::scientific && !uppercase, will use conversion specifier %e 
> If floatfield == std::ios_base::scientific, will use conversion specifier %E
> ```

So Im gonna conclude, that std::cout is also tied to printf